# How could I get value of custom arguments in MSTest vstest console?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest

When I run command: **dotnet vstest AutoTest.dll -- a=a1 b=b1** in cmd prompt, I'd like to get the values of a and b arguments.

I tried to get those values from TestContext, `e.g. TestContext.Properties["a"], TestContext.Properties["b"]` but there is no luck.
Could you please help me on this? How could we pass custom arguments to command and get correctly from code?

Comment: do you find a solution for this?

Comment: @nrofis,
I worked around by using multiple runsettings files. For example, I used 2 runsettings files for defining browser parameter:

chrome.rs:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>`

firefox.rs:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>`

Then you can specify option --Settings:[file name] in the command line. Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then can you use `TestContext.Properties["browser"]` to read them?

Comment: @nrofis, you're welcome! It should be TestContext.Parameters["browser"]

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks strange. Read about custom arguments on [the page](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/dotnet-vstest.md) in "args" section.
And use **TestContext.Properties["a"].ToString();**

Comment: Yes, you're correct. When we use TestContext.Properties["a"], we have to cast it as string, but the error happened because there was no key named "a" existing in the Dictionary<string,object> TestContext.Properties. I just wonder how to pass and  get correctly custom arguments. Do you have any examples about this command?